# Error when set collection dynamically

Tags: arangodb

Blow code is minor modification of :https://www.arangodb.com/tutorials/tutorial-python/

```
doc = {"_key": 'some_nice_key', "name": 'Robert', "age": '56'}
bindVars = {"doc": doc,"collection":"test"}
aql = "INSERT @doc INTO @collection LET newDoc = NEW RETURN newDoc"
queryResult = db.AQLQuery(aql, bindVars = bindVars)
```

,I just made some modification:

```
{"doc": doc}  -> {"doc": doc,"collection":"test"}
INSERT @doc INTO users... -> INSERT @doc INTO @collection...
```

it gives me error:

```
bind parameter 'bind parameter 'collection' has an invalid value or type near '@collection LET newDoc = NEW RET...' at position 1:18' has an invalid value or type (while parsing). Errors: {u'code': 400, u'errorNum': 1553, u'errorMessage': u"bind parameter 'bind parameter 'collection' has an invalid value or type near '@collection LET newDoc = NEW RET...' at position 1:18' has an invalid value or type (while parsing)", u'error': True}
```

Doesn't aql support set collection dynamically or what mistake have I made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AQL supports injecting collection names. But it's a special case where you have to use an additional `@` as a prefix.
https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/aql/fundamentals/bind-parameters/

With these modifications, your code should work:

```
doc = {"_key": 'some_nice_key', "name": 'Robert', "age": '56'}
bindVars = {"doc": doc,"@collection":"test"}
aql = "INSERT @doc INTO @@collection LET newDoc = NEW RETURN newDoc"
queryResult = db.AQLQuery(aql, bindVars = bindVars)
```